# Eclipse Issue - The jar of this class file belongs to container 'Junit4' which does not allow modifications too source attachments of it's entries

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, eclipse-plugin

The jar of this class file belongs to container 'Junit4' which does not allow modifications too source attachments of it's entries. Hello, I get this issue when I try to debug a junit-test and step into the debug line. The code is fully functional on other laptops. Only issue is on my m1 MacBook Air laptop.

2 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRfIM.jpg
1- https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIhOy.jpg
The first image is the actual error I am facing. The second image is the junit code
part and when I try to debug 'step into' code line 118 I get the error . AssertEquals(u1, u2) is the not working part.

Comment: You forgot to include the code/images.

Comment: oh sorry I thought I included it. I have included it in the comment section. If you could help me it would mean a lot

Comment: You can [edit] your question and provide the requested data there. Instead, it appears that you provided the information as a link in an _answer_ - so you should also delete that answer.

Comment: If the information you want to add to your question is text, then please provide it as formatted text - not as an image of text. Why you should not upload [images of code, data, errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12567365) when asking a question.